# Which is the best character encoding for Japanese language for DB, php, and html display?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, character-encoding

i just want to know about the language transation for the Japanese,
1) Which is the best encoding for the database mysql 
2) Which/how can i print that in HTML page. ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I tagged this as language-agnostic since "Japanese" can be really replaced with any other language here.

Comment: "any other language", really? I was under the impression that Japanese had a considerably larger character set than most other languages... silly me.

Comment: Um, "language-agnostic" refers to programming languages, not natural languages. Come to think of it, so does  "language", but it's too vague to be of any use.

Comment: @Alan M: I knew it was a lame joke :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UTF-8 without a doubt. Make everything UTF-8. To put UTF-8 encoded text on your web page, use this within your HEAD tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

As for MySQL, put the following into your my.cnf (config) file:

```
[mysqld]
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

If you're getting garbage characters from the database from queries executed by your application, you might need to execute these two queries *before* fetching your Japanese text:

```
SET NAMES utf8
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: It's easier to just set the default_charset in php

ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );

Comment: Great but he hasn't mentioned PHP anywhere, and putting a meta tag into a document is much simpler than tweaking a setting. Plus, that could fail if he's on a shared host.

Comment: Wait, it's there now, either I didn't see it or it was just added.

Answer (score 5):

Make Sure

1. Database is in UTF8
2. Database Table is in UTF 8
3. Output Headers are in UTF 8
4. HTML Meta Tag is in UTF 8

When everything is talking the encoding you can live happily :)

For MySQL: utf8 charset, utf8_general_ci collation
For PHP headers:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;
```

For HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: thank you very much mr Shadi Almosri...thank you very much....

and could you please tell me..
1. Japanese  - 
2. English
3. French
4. Italian
5. Turkish
6. German
7. Spanish

for all these language into a single system which is more suitable encoding  ???

Comment: UTF8 is made to handel them all very well, i recently released a website in 6 languages including polish, german, spanish, french, italian, greek.  UTF 8 will cover the languages you've specified.

Comment: is there any issue with any browser to display these many languages, i meant in some times i have problems...how you solve that kind of issu with unsupported font characters?

Comment: Just make sure you use a font that supports such charecters in your page.  In this case using something like arial is a safe bet, you can see this by simply going to a web page such as: http://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+website you'll see you don't need anything to display them.  Just ensure all your encoding in every part of your system uses UTF8 and then use a standard font such as arial for the web page display.

Comment: Also the link provided by Peter Bailey is a very useful step by step guide to ensuring the setup i've outlined above is correct. http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Comment: ok...
thank you.. it will be very helpfull for me..

and One more thing.. how can i set this in PGSQL ??

collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
collation-server=utf8_general_ci

????

Comment: What do you use to create your postgres tables? do you have a control panel such as phppgadmin or are you using pure SQL statements?

Comment: Here is a link that might help you for postgresql setup of a unicode db: 

http://www.olat.org/docu/install/Database_and_UTF-8_configuration.html

The line of interest is:

CREATE DATABASE testdb
WITH OWNER = replace_with_your_admin_user_eg_pgsql
ENCODING = 'UNICODE'
TABLESPACE = pg_default;

Comment: am useing another pgsqladmin III application

Comment: Well there should be a function within it when creating the database to set the "Encoding" to "Unicode", that will have the same affect as when creating the MySQL tables.

If all the information so far has been helpful to get you carrying out the requires features, then please tick the answer as "Answered"

Shadi

Answer (score 1):

**Update...**  [*This Q&A*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050010/how-to-set-schema-collation-in-mysql-for-japanese) suggests that `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is best in newer versions of MySQL.