# Data Encoding and Decoding while exporting and importing

Tags: c#, wpf, encoding, decoding

I am exporting data to CSV which may be in Japanese or English. Currently I am exporting it using Encoder UTF8Encoding.

I can see data in Japanese in the CSV file after exporting, but now I want to import this data to my application. Do I need to decode this? While importing I am getting data in the form of digits or other characters.

Comment: Thats a really Good Question! I have the same querry as well.

Comment: What encoding do you use during import? Show your export/import code...

Comment: That's *not* a good question for here... it's clearly *not* a programming problem. It is a business decision. All the same, see [Which is the best character encoding for Japanese language for DB, php, and html display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045338/which-is-the-best-character-encoding-for-japanese-language-for-db-php-and-html) and [Japanese language and computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language_and_computers). The consensus is to use UTF-8.

Comment: Can you show the code..and your efforts?

Comment: could you show your piece of code when encoding /decoding?

Comment: @YuliamChandra while exporting I am getting bytes  like this and writing these bytes to CSV file.                                     byte[] buffer =System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sb.ToString());  where sb is string which is data I am exporting.            What should I use while importing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to decode the same way when you encoded it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var writeText = "你叫什么名字？";
        var writeBytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(writeText);
        File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\test.txt", writeBytes);

        var readBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\test.txt");
        var readText = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetString(readBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(readText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you need to decode it.

Try something like this:

```
private string Decoder(string originFilePath)
{
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(originFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
   {
      return sr.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```