# how to deal with chinese and japanese characters in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on multisite language that is in yii2, I have chinese and japanese language in it, When i insert record with chinese or japanese it is added with `?????` , i have added
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in layouts/main.php file but still in database added character as `????`,

I have other solution to change charset to `utf-8` for each column in database But this will be take too much time 
Is there any simple way to solve this ?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045338/which-is-the-best-character-encoding-for-japanese-language-for-db-php-and-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure db in yii to use utf-8 character set.

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=demo',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
],
```

Go to your phpmyadmin selected the table where you want chinese and japnense words to be inserted and set the property 'collation' to **utf8_general_ci** and now you can insert those words and it will get stored in database as chinese itself.

Comment: Yes i added it for the particular table still no hope

Comment: But i have huge database, If i will alter query for collation of all the fields then it will take too much time, do you have easiest solution for this ?

Comment: No for field it is latin1

Comment: I have too much field, If i will change for all to "utf8 general ci" then it will take too much time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294117/how-to-change-collation-of-database-table-column