# How to set schema collation in MySQL for Japanese

Tags: mysql, collation

I am having a problem with collation. I want to set collation to support the Japanese language. For example, when table.firstname has 'あ', a query with 'ぁ' should return the record. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-cjk.html

Comment: It can be defaulted to the db, table, or override at the column level

Comment: Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045338/which-is-the-best-character-encoding-for-japanese-language-for-db-php-and-html)

Comment: I don't think that this problem has anything to do with 'collation' !?!

Comment: Then share your thought process which might help the PO @stawberry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's like "uppercase" and "lowercase", correct?

```
mysql> SELECT 'あ' = 'ぁ' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
+---------------------------------------+
| 'あ' = 'ぁ' COLLATE utf8_general_ci   |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT 'あ' = 'ぁ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
+---------------------------------------+
| 'あ' = 'ぁ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci   |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     1 |
+---------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT 'あ' = 'ぁ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci;
+-------------------------------------------+
| 'あ' = 'ぁ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci   |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I recommend changing your column to be `COLLATION utf8_unicode_520_ci` (or `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`).

If you expect to be including Chinese, then be sure to use `utf8mb4`.  (Perhaps this advice applies to Kanji, too.)

Comment: thanks for answer, if possible 'あ' = 'ア', what collation or something.

Comment: Should a Hiragana A be treated as equal to a Katakana A?  `...unicode_520_ci` does treat them equal.  That is the best available in utf8/utf8mb4.  See `SHOW COLLATION LIKE '%jap%';` for what is available in other _character sets_.

Comment: It is now 8 years later -- there are _0900_ and _1400_ collations.