# mysql Japanese Characters not displaying correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert Japanese characters and display them, but all I get is gibberish. I have set my database encoding to utf8_general_ci; All columns inherit from table.

The code I am using is:

```
$db = new Database;
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$db->query("INSERT INTO `flash_cards`.`flash_card` (`kanji`) VALUES ('いく')");
$db->execute();
$db->query('select * from flash_card');
$rows = $db->resultset();
print_r('行く');
echo '行く';
print_r(json_encode($rows));
```

The page properly displays the kanji characters when I directly display it to the page, but the problem arises when I pull from the database. Which leads me to believe it's an encoding/decoding problem.

The output I receive is

```
行く行く[{"id":"1","kanji":"\u3044\u304f"},{"id":"2","kanji":"\u3044\u304f"}]
```

I am unsure what else I can do. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out to no avail. I am well aware of several posts throughout stackoverflow, but I am still stuck.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What is your current version of mysql?

Comment: mysql  5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: What happens if you actually output the text?

Comment: I can view it. These characters are printed out from using echo "行く行く"

Comment: That's, uh, nice and all, but I though you said you were having trouble with the data from the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following should work only if your MySQL version is >= 5.6**.

I don't have any Japanese character/database to test but the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050010/how-to-set-schema-collation-in-mysql-for-japanese) suggest that `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` may be better than `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`.

## EDIT

Didn't read that much, sorry just discovered that you used `json_encode()` to get your output.

If you want to get the characters with `json_encode()` you should do the following:

```
print_r(json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Comment: U+3XXX is well within the BMP.

Comment: When trying to do so the characters i get returned are: "\u3044\u304f"

Comment: @o6t9o Updated my answer :)